# HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005)

Tags: experience-editor, security, speak

The Experience Editor is showing the following message:

> A serious error occurred please contact the administrator

Sitecore logs are displaying the following information:

```
6732 11:46:21 ERROR Error processing command url:**/-/speak/request/v1/expeditor/ExperienceEditor.Device.IconLabel** error:System.Web.Mvc.**HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005)**: The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "sitecore\expecteduser", but the current user is "sitecore\Other User".
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)
   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.Process(HttpContext context)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

The Sitecore version is: 8.2 rev 170728

Any help will be appreciated.